# Schema permission giving on all tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to give schema permissions on all tables in a single instance.

For example, I am in `Schema A`, and I need to access the tables in `Schema A` from `Schema B`.

I tried to `grant select on A. * to B` and I am getting an invalid table name.

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: I am getting an error ORA - 00903

Comment: show your code .. a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, there's not a direct way to do this. The easiest shortcut I know is to run something like

```
select 'grant select on A.' || table_name || ' to B;'
from user_tables;
```

And then copy/paste the results and run that.